# How to find project info Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, web-applications

When I setup  a new project in Xcode it asks for template type: page-based app, single view app etc. language, organisation identifier etc. What I want to know is how to find this info for an existing project?

Answer (score 0):

an existing project can have number of views. it does not dependent on template type always. It can vary. like if you select single view application then it will have a one view controller with main file and app delegate file.

But you can also add more view controllers to this project by right click on project nam -> add new file -> ios - source -> cocoa Touch class. etc.

Also if you choose tabbed application then it will have two view controllers with app delegate file. but you can also add more tabs to view by adding more view controllers.

So i mean to say your project structure is not same all the time it can vary based on requirement.

Also you can check your bundle identifier, version and other details by clicking on project name -> click on target and then check your general tab or info file.

[image: Project description image]

Comment: I have a web app I wish to build to iPad which template should I use?

Comment: It depends on your requirement. though you can start with single view applications and add the required controls in a viewController

Comment: Cheers. I'm also not sure about organization identifier, language, or the check boxes at the end?

Comment: see if your existing application is written in objective -c language then their will be .h and .m files and if it is with swift then your viewcontrollers will have extension as swift. for check boxes if your application is build for universal mode then you can run your app in iphone as well as ipad. and organization identifer you can see in info tab.

Comment: I don't think it uses either? There just seems to be html, ccs, js files.

Comment: that means your application is written with the help of cross platform tools.

Comment: if it was written in core ios then it will have above extensions and information

Comment: if you want to convert you web app to ipad app then start with the single view application template. and then add controls as per your requirement. and start the coding.

Comment: Cool cheers man. One last thing. Where do I find the info tab for organization identifier?

Comment: in info tab. look at my image you can see the info tab there you can see the organization name and info

Answer (score -1):

Every template created a different structure of project so you just need to see what is the current structure.
For example: 
Master-Details application has the following description :

```
 This template provides a starting point for a master-detail application,using 
  a split view controller to display a list of items and a detail view.
```

check if the project fits to this description.

You can find the template description by click on it when you create a new project.

[image]

Comment: That is not what i asked